# get specific element inside an element with Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a Mootools element which is a HTML LI element. Inside of it, (child of child), somewhere, there is an input element.

How can I find with Mootools, the input element inside of the li element and retrieve it ?

```
 var input = li. ...
```

Comment: You could use `li.getElement('input');`, that will return the first `input` it finds, you might want to use a more specific CSS selector if there are several inputs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `var input = li.getElement('input');`, that will return the first `input` it finds. `.getElement` is kind of the MooTools `querySelector` before it existed, so it takes a CSS selector.

You might want to use a more specific CSS selector if there are several inputs though.